# OpenGL - Can't get camera to work

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I am having a lot of problems on a tutorial series I am following.( The tutorials can be found here: http://www.antongerdelan.net/opengl/ I am on the Virtual Camera tutorial )

This is my project folder and everything I used( There's too much code to paste here ): 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sohk0uk9h7h2egw/Virtual%20Camera.zip

I am using his math library( math_funcs.h and math_funcs.cpp, and have combined both of them into one header, GLMath.h. You should see it in my project folder. )

Currently, I have tried adding `GLFW_PRESS == glfwGetKey` on each of the keyboard controls, didn't change anything. I know that the program is running the blocks of code because I added some `printf( "You are pressing this key" );` or `printf( "Active" );` in the blocks of code and they were listed in the console. I tried looking at the help info on the bottom of the page and the shader logs don't tell me anything( The shader log is GL.log, also in the project folder ). I did try outputting if the matrix uniform locations were less than 0. The vertex matrix returns 1 and the projection matrix returns 0. Is the projection matrix's uniform location the problem? If so, how would I fix that?
I have also tried using `if ( cam_moved == true )` instead of just `if( cam_moved )`, but that didn't do anything either. Please help, I am stumped and can't figure out how to fix this. My compiler is MinGW and I use Notepad++ as my IDE. I have no problems linking to anything. I use GLFW and GLEW as my window handling library's. Note that I am building all of my OpenGL programs to be cross-compatable with Mac and Linux, so I won't use any Windows functions to simplify things.

Also if you have any suggestions to make the code more efficient, please tell me and explain how it works.

Comment: Please don't use a link to a dropbox share - or any external sources - in your question (except permanent webpages). Mostly because it's likely to be invalid/changed in a year or two but also because it requires that anyone who wants to help you go and download the code, set up a build environment, etc, etc... You should be able to provide the relevant snippets of code and if you can't yet then you need to do more debugging...

Comment: Since i'm new here and I've tried as hard as I could to make the question fit the needs of stackoverflow users who want to help. How would you re-write this question? Cause I doubt adding the 1600-1700 lines of code is good for the question, and not knowing if it's a DLL error or something else like that makes me want to add them to a downloadable link for testing. Especially since I have been debugging for almost a week and knowing the blocks of code were being executed, but not working like they were supposed to, I wouldn't know which snippets of code I would need to include.

Comment: Fair question. I'm sorry if I sounded condescending and yeah, debugging low-level stuff can be a pain for all of us. I'm not an OpenGL expert but I do have some DirectX and WebGL experience, so why don't I download a copy and see if I can help improve the question at all. **Edit:** Just noticed you found an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you instanciate your matrix `T` once and before the loop, its value is never changed.

you need to move the lines 217 `mat4 T=…` and 219 `mat4 view_mat=…` in the `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))`

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. I have spent days trying to figure this out, and by moving the lines that you told me to, as well as 218, the camera started working!

Comment: ah, the line 218 depens on `camera_yaw` somehow missed that… you are welcome